# Why are the answers deleted on a closed question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

In the past questions that are voted to be closed retain the answers accumulated with the question. Why or on what grounds do the answers get deleted with a closed question?

Answer (score 1):

They do not get deleted, unless the question and its answers aren't worth keeping since none of them have a positive score. See [The Community user deleted my question! What gives?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) for some explanation about this automatic process.